# How to populate a filter using ironpython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I tried adding a filtering scheme using the code below, but when I want to populate it with a list ("demandcompounds"), I get the error message AttributeError: 'DataFilteringSelection' object has no attribute 'SetSelection'. What am I doing wrong?

```
Document.Data.Filterings.Add("Test")
filterings = Document.Data.Filterings

for f in filterings:
    if f.Name == "Test":
        f.SetSelection(demandcompounds)
```

Apart from that, I am going to try to create a separate filtering scheme for tens of visualizations using the same table. Is there a more efficient solution to that? By filtering the table without filtering scheme perhaps?